# Git on Cygwin using SSH: Permission denied (publickey) when cloning, but ssh -T git@github.com works

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, git, cygwin

I am having trouble getting cygwin configured to use git with ssh keys on my windows 10 machine.

I installed cygwin's most recent version from their site (setup version 2.925) and added/ensured the packages gcc, git (git, git gui, git svn, gitk), make, vim, and openssh.

I configured the keys for my cygwin instance as I have with other machines previously (including an MSYS2 setup which worked without issue on the same windows machine):

- Generated new keys
- Make sure agent is running
- Add keys to agent
- Add keys to github and authorize my org
- Tested with `ssh -T git@github.com` which output the following:

```
Hi <user>! You've successfully authenticated, (...)
```

However, when I go to `git clone` a repo via ssh, I am unable to access it:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:<org>/<repo>.git
Cloning into <repo>...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
...
```

I am unsure how to resolve this issue as to me it seems like I have configured everything correctly since it is able to authenticate with `ssh` directly.

This makes me ask the following:

- Is it possible that I did not configure the keys correctly and still somehow get that authentication message when testing with `ssh`?
- Is it possible that whatever is happening during the `git clone` is ending up lacking the same environment variables that are available to my terminal when I run `ssh`?
- Is it possible that the MSYS2 setup is causing issues somehow, even if they are not running at the same time?

Some things I have tried:

- Checked that there is no other versions of git running on the windows machine
- Adding/removing various git packages from cygwin on recommendations I have seen on other posts/articles
- Manually adding a `~/.ssh/config` file with the contents

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

**EDIT:**

In an attempt to see more output from the ssh command being run during `git clone` I ran `git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -v" clone <repo address>` and it just worked completely fine. I had first tried setting it as a bash variable which didn't work (either to clone the repo or get more output):

```
$ bash
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"
$ git clone <repo>
```

Which makes me believe that this is indeed an issue of some environment stuff not making it through to wherever the ssh command was used during cloning. Would still love to know the "real" solution here or an explanation of why this happens, hopefully this extra info can point someone in a better direction.